# Git rebase to squash commits reverts local to several commits prior

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase

I made a few commits to my branch and then merged it into master with a CR. I want all the commits to that branch to be squashed, so I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and squashed the two most recent commits into the third most recent commit.

This then modified my local files, producing some sort of hybrid between the current version of master, and master several commits before I merged the CR. Several blocks of code are now encased with

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
{code from before CR merge}
=======
{code from current version of master}
>>>>>>> Branch hash from 8 commits before the CR merge
```

Why does squashing the most recent two commits resurrect changes from 8 commits ago?

I also tried `git reset HEAD~2 --soft`, but `git log` didn't show any changes or indicate that those two commits had been squashed into the other one.

`git log --graph --pretty=%h HEAD~3..HEAD` (after running `git reset HEAD~2 --soft`) produces

```
*   9387a5c
|\  
| * f7624c3
| * f68a001
| * d7729a5
|/  
*   8a1d144
|\  
| * dea1b19
| *   70d5197
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | a5fe680
* | 35b9417
* | 1f3f921
* | ea1d7e5
* | 11a7fb4
* | 021e8c5
* | 5b9db7a
 /  
* b2e4905
```

`9387a5c` is from merging the CR. `git rebase` does not let me squash that commit, only starting from `f7624c3`. I tried to squash `f7624c3` and `f68a001` into `d7729a5` since they were all commits to the same branch for the same feature.

Comment: Is your question about the conflict markers (`<<<`, `===`, and `>>>`) and how to resolve a conflict or why your rebase went awry? The latter cannot be answered without seeing your history of all branches involved. But rebasing a branch _after_ it has been merged sounds fishy to me. What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also post the log graph by `git log --graph --pretty=%h HEAD~3..HEAD` and which 2 commits you try to squash.

Comment: Updated body of question with `git log`

Comment: Looks like one of these merge commits *also* applies a change that isn't in one of its parent commits (i.e. a conflict resolution). I've had mixed luck rebasing a branch with merge commits in it.